# Derived vector: Perform operations

Tags: c++, vector

I have derived from `std::vector<int>` (I know I shouldn't, but I just wanted to test it). Now I can instantiate it and assign some values:

```
MyVector v(5);
v[0]=3;
```

I even can return the value:

```
cout << v[0];
```

But how can I access the value(s) if I want to do some operations within the class? Something like:

```
int func(int a){
   return this->[0] + a; // EXAMPLE
}
```

Comment: `return (*this)[0] + a;` should work.

Comment: `(*this)[0]`, `this->operator[](0)`, `this->at(0)` : note the last one does bounds checking and throws on out of bounds.

Comment: @ThePhD: `operator[](0)` and `at(0)` work without `this->`.

Comment: Very true, so he has a lot of choices. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments under the question:

> return (*this)[0] + a; should work. – didierc 5 hours ago

Additionally, since `vector` lays out memory in a linear fashion (like an array) you can also access the memory which holds the values through a pointer, like so:

```
int *ptr = &(*this)[0];
// read an integer from the console into the 3rd element of the vector
scanf("%d", ptr + 2);
```

This can be useful if you have a `vector` of chars and you need to pass a `char*` to something like a string function, for example.

Be warned however, `vector<bool>` does not behave in the same way (the boolean values are stored internally in bitfields, not an array of bools, see http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/on-vectorbool).